# Ionic4 cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr how to set correct path of static file

Tags: ionic4, ocr

when I follow https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ocr to integrate ocr feature, I cann't set correct path to my static image which is at /src/assets/imgs/test.png:

```
this.ocr.recText(OCRSourceType.NORMFILEURL, "file://path/to/image.png" /*<-this parameter*/)
.then((res: OCRResult) => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
.catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

I tried different combinations:

- /assets/imgs/test.png
- /assets/imgs/test.png
- file://assets/imgs/test.png
- file:///assets/imgs/test.png
- ...

this have frustrated me for a couple days, please help, thanks,

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, do you've found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

the first step you have to create a folder inside the assets folder (lets say its name is images) and put your image inside it.

then write this path in your code "assets/images/yourImage.png"